# Jdbctemplate query for string: EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am using Jdbctemplate to retrieve a single String value from the db.  Here is my method.

```
    public String test() {
        String cert=null;
        String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN 
             where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
        cert = (String) jdbc.queryForObject(sql, String.class); 
        return cert;
    }
```

In my scenario it is complete possible to NOT get a hit on my query so my question is how do I get around the following error message.

```
EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

It would seem to me that I should just get back a null instead of throwing an exception.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

In JdbcTemplate , `queryForInt`, `queryForLong`, `queryForObject` all such methods expects that executed query will return one and only one row. If you get no rows or more than one row that will result in `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` . Now the correct way is not to catch this exception or `EmptyResultDataAccessException`, but make sure the query you are using should return only one row.  If at all it is not possible then use `query` method instead.

```
List<String> strLst = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new RowMapper<String>() {
    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getString(1);
    }
});

if (strLst.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
} else if (strLst.size() == 1) { // list contains exactly 1 element
    return strLst.get(0);
} else { // list contains more than 1 element
         // either return 1st element or throw an exception
}
```

Comment: As mentioned below, the only drawback here is that if the return type was a complex type you would be building multiple objects and instantiating a list, also `ResultSet.next()` would be called unnecessarily. Using a `ResultSetExtractor` is a much more efficient tool in this case.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, why not only `return null` in `catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException exception){ return null; }` ?

Comment: @Rakesh This is not same for all methods like queryForXXX. In case of queryForList it returns a empty list.

Comment: Hey! Can I just ask why 'Now the correct way is not to catch this exception', considering if you're using queryForObject? What would be wrong with catching an exception in the case of queryForObject? 

Thanks :)

Comment: "but make sure the query you are using should return only one row". This is crazy. It's like dictating or forcing the user instead it should have been handled in framework.  I see this as a gap in framework or it is not handled in framework well.. You cannot decide how my query should look like.. If I give a query to framework , it should handle basic stuff.  That's what it is meant for after all..

Comment: Nice explanation, this definitely makes it clear what the issue is, 

The enforcement of 1 row return or your server throws exceptions is beyond stupid but that's just me.

Answer (score 58):

You may also use a [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) instead of a [`RowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html). Both are just as easy as one another, the only difference is you call [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--).

```
public String test() {
    String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN "
                 + " where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
    return jdbc.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<String>() {
        @Override
        public String extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                                                       DataAccessException {
            return rs.next() ? rs.getString("ID_NMB_SRZ") : null;
        }
    });
}
```

The [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) has the added benefit that you can handle all cases where there are more than one row or no rows returned.

**UPDATE**: Several years on and I have a few tricks to share. [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) works superbly with java 8 lambdas which the following examples are designed for but you can quite easily use a static class to achieve the same.

While the question is about simple types, these examples serve as a guide for the common case of extracting domain objects.

First off. Let's suppose that you have an account object with two properties for simplicity `Account(Long id, String name)`. You would likely wish to have a `RowMapper` for this domain object.

```
private static final RowMapper<Account> MAPPER_ACCOUNT =
        (rs, i) -> new Account(rs.getLong("ID"),
                               rs.getString("NAME"));
```

You may now use this mapper directly within a method to map `Account` domain objects from a query (`jt` is a `JdbcTemplate` instance).

```
public List<Account> getAccounts() {
    return jt.query(SELECT_ACCOUNT, MAPPER_ACCOUNT);
}
```

Great, but now we want our original problem and we use my original solution reusing the [`RowMapper`](http://[%60RowMapper%60][2]) to perform the mapping for us.

```
public Account getAccount(long id) {
    return jt.query(
            SELECT_ACCOUNT,
            rs -> rs.next() ? MAPPER_ACCOUNT.mapRow(rs, 1) : null,
            id);
}
```

Great, but this is a pattern you may and will wish to repeat. So you can create a generic factory method to create a new [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) for the task.

```
public static <T> ResultSetExtractor singletonExtractor(
        RowMapper<? extends T> mapper) {
    return rs -> rs.next() ? mapper.mapRow(rs, 1) : null;
}
```

Creating a [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) now becomes trivial.

```
private static final ResultSetExtractor<Account> EXTRACTOR_ACCOUNT =
        singletonExtractor(MAPPER_ACCOUNT);

public Account getAccount(long id) {
    return jt.query(SELECT_ACCOUNT, EXTRACTOR_ACCOUNT, id);
}
```

I hope this helps to show that you can now quite easily combine parts in a powerful way to make your domain simpler.

**UPDATE 2**: Combine with an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for optional values instead of null.

```
public static <T> ResultSetExtractor<Optional<T>> singletonOptionalExtractor(
        RowMapper<? extends T> mapper) {
    return rs -> rs.next() ? Optional.of(mapper.mapRow(rs, 1)) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Which now when used could have the following:

```
private static final ResultSetExtractor<Optional<Double>> EXTRACTOR_DISCOUNT =
        singletonOptionalExtractor(MAPPER_DISCOUNT);

public double getDiscount(long accountId) {
    return jt.query(SELECT_DISCOUNT, EXTRACTOR_DISCOUNT, accountId)
            .orElse(0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

That's not a good solution because you're relying on exceptions for control flow. In your solution it's normal to get exceptions, it's normal to have them in the log.

```
public String test() {
    String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
    List<String> certs = jdbc.queryForList(sql, String.class); 
    if (certs.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return certs.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: my solution might not be the most elegant but at least mine works.  You give an example of queryForObjectList which is not even an option with Jdbctemplate.

Comment: Only drawback here is that if the return type was a complex type you would be building multiple objects and instantiating a list, also `ResultSet.next()` would be called unnecessarily. Using a `ResultSetExtractor` is a much more efficient tool in this case.

Comment: and what if having no value is an option, but not having more than one ? I have this pattern often, and I would like to have a queryForOptionalObject in Spring for this purpose.

Comment: @Guillaume comment on this PR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/724

Answer (score 16):

Ok, I figured it out.  I just wrapped it in a try catch and send back null.

```
    public String test() {
            String cert=null;
            String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN 
                     where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
            try {
                Object o = (String) jdbc.queryForObject(sql, String.class);
                cert = (String) o;
            } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cert;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see why this is so bad and why you received so much downvote for it, appart for being a fundamentalist on the 'no program flow within exception' principle. I would have just replace the printstack trace with a comment explaining  the case and do nothing else.

Comment: This comment is in 2020 and your answer is still valid.. Such a huge gap in framework..

Answer (score 11):

Using Java 8 or above you can use an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and Java Streams.

So you can simply use the `JdbcTemplate.queryForList()` method, create a Stream and use [`Stream.findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) which will return the first value of the Stream or an empty `Optional`:

```
public Optional<String> test() {
    String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
    return jdbc.queryForList(sql, String.class)
            .stream().findFirst();
}
```

To improve the performance of the query you can append `LIMIT 1` to your query, so not more than 1 item is transferred from the database.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, You can play with `JdbcTemplate` and customize your own method as you prefer. My suggestion is to make something like this:

```
public String test() {
    String cert = null;
    String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN
        where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
    ArrayList<String> certList = (ArrayList<String>) jdbc.query(
        sql, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor(new UserMapper()));
    cert =  DataAccessUtils.singleResult(certList);

    return cert;
}
```

It works as the original `jdbc.queryForObject`, but without `throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException` when `size == 0`.

Comment: @Abdull `UserMapper implements RowMapper<String>`.

Comment: `DataAccessUtils.singleResult(...)` is what I was looking for. Thx

Answer (score 8):

Since returning a null when there is no data is something I want to do often when using queryForObject I have found it useful to extend JdbcTemplate and add a queryForNullableObject method similar to below.

```
public class JdbcTemplateExtended extends JdbcTemplate {

    public JdbcTemplateExtended(DataSource datasource){
        super(datasource);
    }

    public <T> T queryForNullableObject(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException {
        List<T> results = query(sql, rowMapper);

        if (results == null || results.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (results.size() > 1) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1, results.size());
        }
        else{
            return results.iterator().next();
        }
    }

    public <T> T queryForNullableObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException {
        return queryForObject(sql, getSingleColumnRowMapper(requiredType));
    }

}
```

You can now use this in your code the same way you used queryForObject

```
String result = queryForNullableObject(queryString, String.class);
```

I would be interested to know if anyone else thinks this is a good idea?

Comment: It is, and it should be in Spring

Answer (score 5):

You can do this way:

```
String cert = DataAccessUtils.singleResult(
    jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
        "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN where ID_STR_RT = :id_str_rt and ID_NMB_SRZ = :id_nmb_srz",
        new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("id_str_rt", "999")
            .addValue("id_nmb_srz", "60230009999999"),
        String.class
    )
)
```

**DataAccessUtils.singleResult** + **queryForList**:

- returns null for empty result
- returns single result if exactly 1 row found
- throws exception if more then 1 rows found. Should not happen for primary key / unique index search

[DataAccessUtils.singleResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/support/DataAccessUtils.html#singleResult-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 3):

Since getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap expects minimum size of one but when it returns null it shows EmptyResultDataAccesso fix dis when can use below logic

```
Map<String, String> loginMap =null;
try{
    loginMap = getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap(sql, new Object[] {CustomerLogInInfo.getCustLogInEmail()});
}
catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex){
    System.out.println("Exception.......");
    loginMap =null;
}
if(loginMap==null || loginMap.isEmpty()){
    return null;
}
else{
    return loginMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a group function so that your query always returns a result.
ie

```
MIN(ID_NMB_SRZ)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can make almost any single value query return a value or null by wrapping it:

```
SELECT (SELECT <query>) AS value
```

and hence avoid complexity in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

We can use query instead of queryForObject,  major difference between query and queryForObject is that query return list of Object(based on Row mapper return type) and that list can be empty if no data is received from database while queryForObject always expect only single object be fetched from db neither null nor multiple rows and in case if result is empty then queryForObject throws EmptyResultDataAccessException, I had written one code using query that will overcome the problem of EmptyResultDataAccessException in case of null result.

> ```
> ----------
>
>
> public UserInfo getUserInfo(String username, String password) {
>       String sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname,address,city FROM users WHERE id=? and pass=?";
>       List<UserInfo> userInfoList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] { username, password },
>               new RowMapper<UserInfo>() {
>                   public UserInfo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
>                       UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
>                       user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
>                       user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
>                       user.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
>                       user.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
>
>                       return user;
>                   }
>               });
>
>       if (userInfoList.isEmpty()) {
>           return null;
>       } else {
>           return userInfoList.get(0);
>       }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this before & had posted in the spring forums.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/123129-frustrated-with-emptyresultdataaccessexception

The advice we received was to use a type of SQlQuery.  Here's an example of what we did when trying to get a value out of a DB that might not be there.

```
@Component
public class FindID extends MappingSqlQuery<Long> {

        @Autowired
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

                String sql = "Select id from address where id = ?";

                super.setDataSource(dataSource);

                super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));

                super.setSql(sql);

                compile();
        }

        @Override
        protected Long mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return rs.getLong(1);
        }
```

In the DAO then we just call...

```
Long id = findID.findObject(id);
```

Not clear on performance, but it works and is neat.

Answer (score 0):

For Byron, you can try this..

```
public String test(){
                String sql = "select ID_NMB_SRZ from codb_owner.TR_LTM_SLS_RTN 
                     where id_str_rt = '999' and ID_NMB_SRZ = '60230009999999'";
                List<String> li = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,String.class);
                return li.get(0).toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to make

```
    jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, String.class)
```

work, make sure your jdbcTemplate is of type

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO returning a `null` is a bad solution because now you have the problem of sending and interpreting it at the (likely) front end client.
I had the same error and I solved it by simply returning a `List<FooObject>`.
I used `JDBCTemplate.query()`.

At the front end (Angular web client), I simply examine the list and if it is empty (of zero length), treat it as no records found.

Answer (score 0):

I got same exception while using

```
if(jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("select * from table").size() > 0 ) /* resulted exception */
```

when changed to list it resolved

```
if(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from table").size() > 0) /* no exception */
```

Comment: `jdbcTemplate.queryForMap()` expects a single row.  You'd have to add something like `LIMIT 1` for your example to work.

Answer (score -2):

I just catch this "EmptyResultDataAccessException"

```
public Myclass findOne(String id){
    try {
        Myclass m = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "SELECT * FROM tb_t WHERE id = ?",
                new Object[]{id},
                new RowMapper<Myclass>() {
                    public Myclass mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        Myclass m = new Myclass();
                        m.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                        return m;
                    }
                });
        return m;
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) { // result.size() == 0;
        return null;
    }
}
```

then you can check:

```
if(m == null){
    // insert operation.
}else{
    // update operation.
}
```

Comment: We can use query instead of queryForObject

Comment: Usually considered bad practice to abuse exceptions like this. Exceptions are not for predictable program logic flow, they are for exceptional situations.