# Getting incorrect result size exception while running jdbc spring mvc login

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

```
@Override
public int getData(String username, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int Status = 1;
    String sql = "select UserId from UserRegister where UserName=? and Password=? and Status=?;";
    int userid = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { username,
            password, Status }, Integer.class);
    if (userid != 0) {
        return userid;
    } else {
        userid = 0;
        return userid;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect
result size: expected 1, actual 0
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606229/jdbctemplate-query-for-string-emptyresultdataaccessexception-incorrect-result

Comment: here the parameters along with the query is integer values. if we need to pass the parameters along with the query what we will do?

Answer (score 0):

try it once it may helps you.

```
String sql = "select UserId from UserRegister where UserName=? and Password=?  and Status=?";
int userid = (Integer)jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql, new Object[] { username,
        password, Status }, Integer.class);
```

Comment: thanku for your answer ,but i not works for me..here some problem with the queryforobject returns should be atleast one . thatsy exception is coming. could u say about that?